# Why does std::counting_semaphore::acquire() suffer deadlock in this case?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, semaphore

I am testing `std::counting_semaphore` on C++20 with Windows 10 and MinGW x64.

As I learned from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore, `std::counting_semaphore` is an atomic counter. We can use `release()` to increase the counter, and use `acquire()` to decrease the counter. If the counter equals to 0, than the thread wait.

I build the following simplified example to show my problem.
If I always `release()` before `acquire()` in the thread, the internal counter value(v) of `std::counting_semaphore` should always stay between v and v+1, and this code should never suffer any block.

When I run this example code, it suffers deadlock very often, but sometimes it can finish correctly.

I try to use `std::cout` message to understand the deadlock situation, but the deadlock disappeared when I using `std::cout`. In another hand, the deadlock disappeared when I use `std::unique_lock`.

The example is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <semaphore>

using namespace std::literals;

std::mutex mtx;

const int numOfThr {2};
const int numOfForLoop {1000};
const int max_smph {numOfThr* numOfForLoop *2};

std::counting_semaphore<max_smph> smph {numOfThr+1};

void thrf_TestSmph ( const int iThr )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfForLoop; ++i )
    {
//        std::unique_lock ul(mtx);
        //unique_lock can stop deadlock.

        smph.release(); //smph counter ++
        smph.acquire(); //smph counter --

//        if ( i % 1000 == 1 ) std::cout << iThr << " : " << i << "\n";
        //print out message can stop deadlock.
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start testing semaphore ..." << "\n\n";

    std::vector<std::thread> thrf_TestSmphVec ( numOfThr );

    for ( int iThr = 0; iThr < numOfThr; ++iThr )
    {
        thrf_TestSmphVec[iThr] = std::thread ( thrf_TestSmph, iThr );
    }

    for ( auto& thr : thrf_TestSmphVec )
    {
        if ( thr.joinable() )
            thr.join();
    }

    std::cout << "Test is done." << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `acquire()` do some work `release()` in your thread?

Comment: This is a test example for a specific problem of semaphore, so I put the ```release()``` before ```acquire()``` in order to avoid the thread being blocked by semaphore. However, even they are in the "non-blocking" sequence order, the code still be blocked.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek, That's not _the_ way that one _should_ use a semaphore. That is _one_ way that one _can_ use a semaphore: One can use a semaphore as if it was a mutex. But that's not a very interesting case because we already have `std::mutex`. "Semaphore" is a very old idea. It dates back to the early 1960s. It was intended to be a low-level mechanism upon which higher-level "synchronization" mechanisms could be built. [It can be used in many ways](https://greenteapress.com/wp/semaphores/).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Semaphore is an old and epic function. However, ```std:counting_semephore``` is a new function in C++20. According to my experimentation, when you want to control the total users of a resource, ```std::counting_semaphore``` is much faster than ```std::unique_lock()``` with ```std::condition_variable```. That is the reason why I am studying it.

Answer (score 8):

Update: Found this bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104928

---

This is not really an answer.

I can reproduce the infinite blocking on my M1 macbook air, when it is compiled with gcc or clang and libstdc++. Printing message did't prevent the blocking. When it is compiled with clang and libc++, the program finished normally.

I noticed this piece of code and comment in my included header `include/c++/11/bits/semaphore_base.h` of libstdc++:

```cpp
    _GLIBCXX_ALWAYS_INLINE void
    _M_release(ptrdiff_t __update) noexcept
    {
      if (0 < __atomic_impl::fetch_add(&_M_counter, __update, memory_order_release))
          return;
      if (__update > 1)
          __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, true);
      else
          __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, true);
// FIXME - Figure out why this does not wake a waiting thread
//  __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, false);
    }
```

Then I changed the first `return` to `__atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, true);`, and the problem seems disappear.

That comment is commited in [this commit](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/e02840c1a92abecd211ffaf05b28329bcb534583).

```cpp
    _GLIBCXX_ALWAYS_INLINE void
    _M_release(ptrdiff_t __update) noexcept
    {
      if (0 < __atomic_impl::fetch_add(&_M_counter, __update, memory_order_release))
          return;
      if (__update > 1)
          __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, true);
      else
-         __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, false);
+         __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, true);
+ // FIXME - Figure out why this does not wake a waiting thread
+ //    __atomic_notify_address_bare(&_M_counter, false);
```

It seems that the developer team has known the problem, but their short-term solution didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. After reading the links you provided, they are similar problems as mine.    It means that ```std::counting_semaphore``` is not reliable at this moment.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of experimentations about `std::counting_semaphore::acquire()`, I noticed that it will suffer a blocking when two threads trigger `std::counting_semaphore::acquire()` in a very close time interval. It seems to make the internal counter inside of the `std::counting_semaphore` be frozen, so
`std::counting_semaphore::release()` can not increase the internal counter of the `std::counting_semaphore` correctly. In this situation, the next `std::counting_semaphore::acquire()` will be blocked, because the internal counter is frozen. This situation happens in a lot of intense threads experimentations with `std::counting_semaphore::acquire()` on my system. The example code in my question is the most simplified one to reproduce this problem.

I guess it is a kind of collision issue inside of my system. Base on this assumption, I try to use back-off to bypass this problem.
I use `while(!std::counting_semaphore::try_acquire_for(1ns)){}` to substitude `std::counting_semaphore::acquire()`, because `std::counting_semaphore::try_acquire_for()` can return `false` when it can not decrease the internal counter.

It works well at this moment, even I increase the `const int numOfThr {2}` to `` {100`000} ``.

Here comes the example code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <semaphore>

using namespace std::literals;

std::mutex mtx;

const int numOfThr {2}; 
const int numOfForLoop {1000};
const int max_smph {numOfThr* numOfForLoop * 2};

std::counting_semaphore<max_smph> smph {numOfThr + 1};

void thrf_TestSmph ( const int iThr )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < numOfForLoop; ++i )
    {
        smph.release(); //smph counter ++
        while ( !smph.try_acquire_for ( 1ns ) ) {} //smph counter --
        //don't use smph.acquire() directly, it easily makes blocking.
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start testing semaphore ..." << "\n\n";

    std::vector<std::thread> thrf_TestSmphVec ( numOfThr );

    for ( int iThr = 0; iThr < numOfThr; ++iThr )
    {
        thrf_TestSmphVec[iThr] = std::thread ( thrf_TestSmph, iThr );
    }

    for ( auto& thr : thrf_TestSmphVec )
    {
        if ( thr.joinable() )
            thr.join();
    }

    std::cout << "Test is done." << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By the way, I noticed that ```std::binary_semaphore::acquire()``` suffers the similar deadlock. It will be easier to reproduce the problem by increasing ```numOfThr {2}``` higher, such as ```{1000}```.